# Why isn't this variable defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I added a label onto the end of the program to make sure that the variable found was correct and was being displayed, however when I run the program, it is saying that 'loggedIn is not defined' even though I have stated the variable before the subroutine. This is not allowing the test label to be shown. Does anybody know a reason for this?

Here is my code:

```
loggedIn = ""

def done():
    checkID = txtCID.get()
    checkPassword = txtCPassword.get()

    with open("employees.txt", "r") as empList:
        for i in empList:
            fields = i.split(", ")
            if len(fields) < 2:
                continue
            chID = fields[0]
            if chID == checkID.upper():
                exPassword = fields[12]
                chPassword = str(exPassword)
                if chPassword == checkPassword:
                    global loggedIn
                    loggedIn = i
                    show_frame(entries_frame1)
        else:
            txtCID.delete(0,END)
            txtCPassword.delete(0,END)


btnDone=Button(login_frame2,command=done,text="Login", width=15, font=("Calibri", 16, "bold"),     fg="white", bg="black")
btnDone.grid(row=3, column=2)
btnCancel=Button(login_frame2,command=lambda:show_frame(login_frame),text="Cancel", width=15, font=  ("Calibri", 16, "bold"), fg="white", bg="black")
btnCancel.grid(row=3, column=4)

loggedInlbl=Label(entries_frame1,text=loggedIn,font=("Calibri", 16), bg="lightgrey")
loggedInlbl.grid(row=2, column=10, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Comment: It is defined; please provide a [mcve] that proves otherwise. (You don't need to define a Tk interface to reproduce the error, if there is in fact an error.)

Comment: But the assignment statement is executed because it takes me to the desired frame, it also doesn't stop the code, it just says in the assistant tab that loggedIn is undefined

Comment: Ok, you are observing a static analysis tool, not Python itself, that doesn't recognize that `loggedIn` is supposed to be global.

Comment: Moved the global statement to before the checkID variable and it still doesnt output the label

Comment: I also included a print function and it does not print

Comment: Where are you *calling* `done`? This code doesn't call it until you click the button, which is *after* you use the value of `loggedIn` to create the `Label` object.

Comment: When you execute `loggedInlbl = Label(entries_frame1, text=loggedIn, ...)`, the value of `loggedIn` is still the empty string. The `Label` instance won't update after `done` is called and changes the value of the name `loggedIn`.

Comment: AHHHHH sorry fella I get it now, once I included the label into the subroutine, it outputted the correct variable. Just wondering how would I test to see if the variable is correct outside of the subroutine as for some reason when I call a print(loggedIn) function after the cancel btn, it is not displayed in the shell

Comment: Lots of competing issues to make it difficult to find the actual problem :) The `global` statement is documented as being in effect for the current *code block*, which is different from a scope, but CPython at least seems to treat the entire current scope as one code block for purposes of interpreting the meaning of the `global` statement. (That's why I initially thought the location of the `global` statement was relevant.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a `StringVar` object, not a regular `str`, to link the text of the label to changes made by `done` when it is called.

```
from tkinter import StringVar, Label

loggedIn = StringVar("")

# Since you aren't *assigning* to the name loggedIn, you don't need
# a global statement at all.
def done():
    ...
    loggedIn.set(str(i))
    ...

...

# textvariable, not text, so that the Label will monitor changes
# to the StringVar object.
loggedInlbl = Label(entries_frame1, textvariable=loggedIn, ...)
```

Initially, the label will contain the empty string, but once you click your done button, you should see the label change (assuming `loggedIn.set` gets called by `done`).

---

The error about `loggedIn` not being defined appears to be a static analysis tool not understanding the unorthodox location of your original `global` statement, not anything to do with Python actually defining the variable.

Comment: Hi, this prints loggedIn, however instead of it printing out the object itself, it prints out (PY_VAR2) and I desire the output (SUTD01, Sutton, Derek, e, e, e, e, ...), is this because it isnt being translated to a string correctly?

Comment: You need `loggedIn.getvalue()` to get the underlying `str` it currently wraps.

Comment: @chepner just a heads-up: it's just `get()` not `getvalue()`. OP: you'll want to do something like `print(loggedIn.get())`

Comment: Thanks, you’d think I would have realized that given the name `set`.